# test covergence of power serial $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n^{1000}}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n^{1000}}x^n$$
I am trying to test covergence and find set of such $x$s that it is covergent.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_n\right|}=\infty$$

$$R=\left[\frac{1}{\infty}\right]=0$$
Now, seems to me that my set of covergence is $(0,0)=\emptyset$.
However, I am not sure what exactly does mean $R=0$.  In some cases we don't get limit...

I know, that I should consider $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_n\right|}$.

I think that I don't understand it exactly. Can someone try to explain it me ?

Comment: $R=0$ means that the power series only converges for $x=0$. Any power series centered at zero will converge when $x=0$, because then at most one term is non-zero.

Comment: $R=0$ means that the power series is convergent *iff* $x=0$.

Comment: Try Stirling's approximation to the factorial, it will probably help.

Comment: I don't think this makes any sense for $n=0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I think the OP has already obtained the value of $R$ which is $0$. He is asking about the meaning of $R=0$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh, ok.

Comment: Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n^{1000}}x^n>\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^{1000}}$$

Apply the ratio test.  (Just a different way to test convergence)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe, somebody can give more details about this subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A power series around a point $\;x_0\;$ , **any** such power series, always converges for $\;x=x_0\;$ , since

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n\implies f(x_0)=a_0$$

assuming, of course, the series is defined for $\;n=0\;$ .

If *only* for this value the series converges then we say its radius of convergence is zero $\;(R=0)\;$, and the interval of convergence, if you insists in having one, is simply $\;[x_0,x_0]=\{x_0\}\;$

You used the ratio test to check the convergence radius, but you could as well check that with the [Cauchy-Hadamard Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem):

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(n!)^{1/2}}}{n^{1000/n}}=\infty\implies R=0$$

and since your series is centered at $\;x_0=0\;$ then  only for this value it converges.

By the way and being strictly formal, your series should begin with $\;n=1\;$...but this is unimportant for the main stuff above.